# Enterprise Architect : как на диаграмме сделать поле final

Tags: uml

В атрибутах нет ни `final`, ни `const`, ни `readOnly`...
Не знаю, что и делать.
[image: Enterprise Architect]

Comment: а это чудо не умеет заводить кастомные значения? тогда вы выбрали не тот инструмент для создания архитектуры. нагуглите Power Designer. Лучше него пока еще ни чего не придумано.

Comment: в универе за меня выбрали. не знаю про кастомные значения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если построить диаграмму по существующему коду, то в диаграмме после типа переменной, которая в коде была объявлена `final`, будет указано ограничение `{readOnly}`. Выглядит это вот так:

`x: int {readOnly}`

Это ограничение можно ввести вручную (просто нажав по нужному полю в классе). Построенный по такой диаграмме код действительно будет иметь `final` поле.

Если просто добавить стереотип `<<final>>`, то построенный по такой диаграмме код не будет содержать поле с атрибутом `final`.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/software_engineering/java_conventions.html

Эти атрибуты можно выставить в настройках `Stereotypes`